# How to access this user control in Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have one user control in my WPF app

```
 <UserControl x:Class="NewWPFApp.ProgressControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Headerval}">
        <StackPanel Margin="10,4,0,0">
            <DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=records}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

and in my `Mainwindow` when I am doing this

```
<Window xmlns:NewWPFApp="clr-namespace:NewWPFApp"  x:Class="NewWPFApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="peopleListBox" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
                    <NewWPFApp:ProgressControl Height="100" Width="100"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I cant see the output.
If I remove it from the Data template then it works.But not inside the data template.

What am I missing ???

Thanks

Comment: You've provided a template for ListBox Items, but you haven't created any items?

Comment: I need to add collection of my usercontrol into the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.ItemTemplate` specifies how items added to a list box will be displayed. In your case, you uses your own custom control. However, at the same time you added no items to the list box so there is nothing to display. To populate the list box you can use binding e.g.:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsToBeDisplayed}" x:Name="peopleListBox" >
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Where `ItemsToBeDisplayed` is a property of a view model (if you use MVVM pattern) that returns a collection of objects. If not you can populate `ItemsSource` without using binding:

```
var list = new List<People>();
//Add objects to a list
peopleListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

I assumed that you have `People` class that models people you want to display in your application.  `People` class should have `Headerval` and `records` properties because you use them in your your `ProgressControl` control. If you do as described, a new instance of your `ProgressControl` control will be created for every object in `ItemsSource`.